# How to prevent overriding from button styles in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, styles, devexpress

out current application is a DevExpress Ribbon window. However, we have some legacy code - including a WPF Control which was hosted through a WinForms Window - with WPF Host. (please dont ask why)

I wanted to change the UserControl at least to a Wpf Window to get rid of WinForms.

Now here is my Problem: All stlyes get totally messed up. Especially my buttons have a problem:

The buttons lose their assigned Images, and also Background and Foreground is not assignable. Through the Live Visual Tree from Studio I see that it is overridden.

[image]

I guess the thing with images leads to the same root cause.
I dont want to redo the whole window again in DevExpress (if this is the cause).

Is there a way for a window to not use some application styles and run as default? Or how can I find out, what is actually overriding everything?

Comment: Update: The images of button was hidden due to some issue with size (it was to small now that all the styles changed...) So this is fixed. but still desparate about background issue.

Comment: This would be a tough one to hunt down the culprit(s) without seeing some more code or perhaps a way to reproduce? However I imagine it could cause some issue considering its use in a color picker so if you can provide some more detail to troubleshoot with it would be helpful.

Comment: For the moment I solved the issue, adding a rectangle to the button content, and giving the color to it. But I will try to create a sample application, which reproduces it, asap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the [solution](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q395000/turn-off-a-theme-on-a-control). The DevExpress was overriding any styles of any form in application, settings something to the DevExpress.Xpf.CoreTemeManager.

To disable a style, I had to add the following thing to my window:

```
<Window x:Class="AnotherWindow"
    xmlns:dx="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/core"
    dx:ThemeManager.ThemeName="NoneName"
   <!-- ...-->
</Window>
```

Also include DevExpress.Data and DevExpress.Xpf.Core references.